# What should I use to run HTML/CSS/JS code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a few simple HTML/CSS/JS games. This time a few friends and I are going to create another game that people can download from some website. We want to use HTML CSS and JS even though that is probably not the best option.

All the games I created before I've used Chrome to run them. Of course I can't just make people run my games with Chrome. So how should I run it?

Comment: This isn't a good question for SO. But you need a web server to serve the static pages. You can probably just use something GoDaddy's shared hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Electron (http://electron.atom.io/). You can use it to build desktop apps using Html/Css/Js.

Comment: Yes. I think I will use this, thanks.